# Fluctuation of number of particles in one state in canonical ensemble

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function

I haven't touched statistical physics for a while and am stuck in quite a basic question, and surprisingly, I cannot find any information in the internet that helps me to think it through. 
What is the variance of a number of particles $N_{j}$ located in a particular state, say, a state j with energy $E_{j}$?

Answer (score 1):

You will Need the Grand canonical Ensemble, this Features fluctuations of particles. It is given by the probability Density function

$\rho_j(E_j,N_j) = e^{\mu_j N_j-N_jE_j/(k_B T)}$.

Consider the Partition function

$\Omega(E_j) = \ln\sum_{N_j=0}^\infty \rho_j(E_j,N_j)$.

Differentiationg this Expression by chemical potential $\mu_j$ leads to

$\frac{\partial \Omega(E_j)}{\partial \mu_j} = \sum_{N_j=0}^\infty N_j\rho_j(E_j,N_j)/\Omega(E_j) = <N_j>$.

Note that the $\Omega(E_j)$ still depends on the chemical potential. Differentiation of this expression once again by the chemical potential, you get the fluctuation in particle number.

Above Partition function generates the cumulants. The first cumulant (= 1st derivative) gives you the average and the second one (= 2nd derivative) is the variance.